# Enable and Disable IPv4 and IPv6 of an adapter programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp

Is it possible to Enable/Disable the IPv4 and IPv6 protocols for a selected network adapter using C# and  .Net libraries or the registry?

Comment: the basic idea is to get the same result as if you uncheck the IPv4 and/or IPv6 checkbox in the network properties window. If it can be done using the registry without having to reboot that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the example [How to disable IPv6 programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/07/17/how-to-enabledisable-ipv6-programmatically-in-windows-vista/) , but it doesn't work on my PC.

However, I found another way to solve the problem without editing the registry directly.

### First, I will show you how to solve this problem using PowerShell.

We have many ways to get the name of NIC, for example execute the following command on PowerShell:

> Get-NetAdapter

*Let's assume the NIC name is "Ethernet".*

To enable IPv6, execute the following command on PowerShell:

> enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name 'Ethernet' -ComponentID ms_tcpip6

To disable IPv6, execute the following command on PowerShell:

> disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name 'Ethernet' -ComponentID ms_tcpip6

To get all ComponentIDs of the NIC, execute the following command on PowerShell:

> Get-NetAdapterBinding -name 'Ethernet'

### Now, I will show you how to do this using C#.

1.Install the nuget package which named "Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies" to your project

2.If you want to disable IPv6, use the following code

```
using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powerShell.AddScript("Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name 'Ethernet' -ComponentID ms_tcpip6");
    powerShell.Invoke();
    if (powerShell.HadErrors)
    {
        // Failed, do something
        return;
    }
    // Success, do something
    return;
}
```

3.Now, I believe that you have already know how to perform other similar operations.

Comment: That code is not working on windows 7 and prior windows versions (especially Get-NetAdapterBinding and other functions are not available at all). moreover the powershell syntax can be changed from version to version. So, if you want to make really portable application - the only way is to use Windows API, but not the Admin tools like Powershell or netsh.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at : http://eniackb.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-2008.html

Basically modify registry to do same as you would using GUI.

Comment: I would like to remind that editing registry is a hack fix and you should be aware what you are doing.

Comment: when you say hack fix, does that make it less recommended or not advised to use?

Comment: I think what he means is "not officially supported". Microsoft creates APIs to abstract out things like this. They can change the location in the registry or other details, and as long as a program is using the API to effect the change, it's safe. There's also features in Windows where the data is stored in the registry as a backward-compat fix. [Apps start relying on the data in the registry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.11.windowsconfidential.aspx), instead and doing the correct thing and using an API. Then, one day MS yanks the fix from the OS and your app stops working.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `INetCfgBindingPath::Enable` then `INetCfg::Apply` method (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547947(v=vs.85).aspx)). Please look into code example for details: [how to disable ipv6 programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/07/17/how-to-enabledisable-ipv6-programmatically-in-windows-vista/).

As far as I know [nvspbind](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Network-VSP-Bind-cf937850) can disable or enable IPv6 on specified adapter without rebooting PC. And I think `nvspbind` is based on `INetCfg` API.